# Inheritance concerns between Square/Rectangle (with constrained invariants) which share Quadrilateral base

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an interface Polygon, and then I have a class Quadrilateral. Then, I have two classes, Square and Rectangle, which extends the Quadrilateral.

Quadrilateral consists of the instance variables sideA, sideB, sideC, and sideD. It contains the methods area() and perimeter() to compute the area and perimeter of any quadrilateral.

With that in mind, the class Square has one instance variable, lengthOfSides, and the class Rectangle has two instance variables, length and width.

Since the methods area and perimeter in Quadrilateral can be used for calculating the area and perimeter of any quadrilateral, including a square and rectangle, I thought it would be best to just construct a Square or Rectangle and then call the super class to assign the sides (needed in Quadrilateral for area and perimeter calculations). In addition, when the instance variables in Square or Rectangle are changed, the setters also update the associated values in the parent classes.

Here is the Square class:

```
/**
 * A model for a Square.
 * 
 * @author BTKS
 */
public class Square extends Quadrilateral {

    private static final double ANGLES_SUM = 180; // the total sum of two opposite angles in degrees

    private double lengthOfSides; // the length of each side

    /**
     * Construct a new Square.
     * 
     * @param lengthOfSides the length of each side
     */
    public Square(double lengthOfSides) {
        super(ANGLES_SUM, lengthOfSides, lengthOfSides, lengthOfSides, lengthOfSides);

        this.lengthOfSides = lengthOfSides;
    }

    /**
     * @return the length of each side
     */
    public double getLengthOfSides() {
        return lengthOfSides;
    }

    /**
     * @param lengthOfSides the length of each side
     */
    public void setLengthOfSides(double lengthOfSides) {
        this.lengthOfSides = lengthOfSides;

        super.setSideA(lengthOfSides);
        super.setSideB(lengthOfSides);
        super.setSideC(lengthOfSides);
        super.setSideD(lengthOfSides);
    }
}
```

Is this considered bad practice? This is for a college assignment, and she didn't specify what she was looking for. It seemed useless to extend the class Quadrilateral if I were to not use anything from Quadrilateral in Square.

Comment: Yes, it's generally considered bad practice - but it is somewhat controversial. The nub of the problem is that if you have a Square instance and call mySquare.setSideA(newLength) one of two things will happen - either your square will have a side that's not the same length as its other sides, or sides B, C and D will "magically" get set to other values. The rule of thumb that I've heard to resolve this is that "square values" (or immutable squares) are "IS-A" quadrilateral value, but that "square variable" (or mutable squares) are not IS-A quadrilateral variable.

Comment: If Quadrilateral only had (abstract) `getSide{N}` methods - but no `sideN` fields or setters - then this would not be an issue as the square/rectangle invariants would be guarded by the appropriate 'shaper' in the subtypes and the `getSide{N}` accessors would be implemented as appropriate .. but then one could not create a true Quadrilateral if it was abstract ..

Comment: Would it then be best to just override area and perimeter in Square and Rectangle, and not really use the Quadrilateral instance variables? I believe the goal of this assignment is to learn inheritance and encapsulation, but this doesn't seem like the best example for learning it.

Comment: Just as a reference: The [Principles of OOD by Uncle Bob](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) contain an [article about the rectange/square issue](http://docs.google.com/a/cleancoder.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0BwhCYaYDn8EgNzAzZjA5ZmItNjU3NS00MzQ5LTkwYjMtMDJhNDU5ZTM0MTlh&hl=en) in view of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - also see related questions, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142543/does-this-solve-the-liskov-substitution-square-rectangle-violation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you want the "inheritance" relationship to represent here. Often, what one wants to express is best NOT expressed using what is called "object-oriented inheritance" (indeed, I have found few uses for this kind of inheritance).

In this case, the inheritance relationship seems to express the fact that the subclass has "additional constraints" relative the superclass. If Polygon were a class in itself rather than an interface:

- Polygon (anything goes, as long as it is convex)
- Quadrilateral (additional constraint of having only 4 edges)
- Rectangle (additional constraint of having Pi/2 angles)
- Square (additional constraint of having identical edge lengths)

Basically, I would:

Either just program out the `Quadrilateral`, remove the setters and make all instance variables final. This gets rid of phenomena whereby you get uncontrolled changes in a `Square` if someone changes the sides individually. (Generally finals are a Good Idea). Subclasses then reduce to just having special constructors.

Or program out the `Quadrilateral` only, do not subclass, give it boolean checks: `isRectangle()`, `isSquare()`, and maybe leave the setters. But that sounds less elegant.

Also recommending Bertrand Meyer's ["The many faces of inheritance: a taxonomy of taxonomy"](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=494093) (1996) if you can find it, it's paywalled but there is probably someone with IEEE Xplore access nearby.

Comment: I like the approach of removing the setters and making all of the instance variables final. Thank you!

Comment: I started making as much as possible final after I read ["A little Java, A few Patterns"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/little-java-few-patterns) which came heavily influenced by functional language traditions. Once you notice how many gordian knots just go away when you do that you will never go back (though the garbage collector will have to work heavily).